# SupportMapFragment on scroll gesture listener?

Tags: android, google-maps

Is it possible to detect OnScrollGesture listener for SupportMapFragment.  This was a question I tried tackling some time back but couldn't find a solution. I am trying to detect whether a user scrolls.  I don't want to check for camera update or location change.  I am assuming if there is no solution I would have to check to see if camera position is equal to current location.  Is there a simple solution to this?

I know you can disable to Scroll gestures.

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the listeners you can set on a GoogleMap instance [here in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener.html)

I would assume the OnCameraChangeListener is something you could use, since when a user scrolls, the camera is updated.

> GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener
>
> Defines signatures for methods that are called when the camera changes position.

Comment: I am updating the camera based on location change which would cause a conflict with that method. I have gone through a lot of documentation looking for a solution but have come up dry.

Comment: @EugeneH I imagine you could fix that with a simple `if` construction

Comment: 'setOnCameraChangeListener(GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java 

please udpate